# ngb timepicker override fieldset css styles

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

I am using ngbootstrap in my application and for time control am using ngb time picker, when i used it, it comes wrapped with fieldset by default, any suggestions on how to not show time picker with fieldset around it. This is how i am seeing it with fieldset [Time Control Image with fieldset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sm5Ci.png) and in developer tools it shows that ngbtimepicker has fieldset in it [ngbtimepicker html here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ga0yI.png)

Below is my html code

```
 <ngb-timepicker ngb-timepicker (ngModelChange)="onTimeChange($event)" [seconds]="true" 
  [hourStep]="hourStep" [minuteStep]="minuteStep" [secondStep]="secondStep"></ngb-timepicker>
```

I am trying to achieve this [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kySaP.png)

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

looking into [ng-bootstrap time picker sources](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/timepicker/timepicker.ts), I see no opportunity to remove the `fieldset` tag. Most likely it is needed for accessibility reasons. I suppose you can only change the visual appearance of the `fieldset`. Looking into the pictures provided, I suppose you need to remove border from the `fieldset`. The solution would look somewhat like

```css
fieldset {
   border: none;
}
```

Depending on your app, you might consider use different css selector.

Answer (score 0):

To customize css atributes from a ng bootstrap component, you need to use:

```
    ::ng-deep ngb-timepicker fieldset{
      border: none !important;
    }
```